# Notify email when Azure Storage table gets new entry

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there an inbuilt way to notify an email when a new entry is added to the Table?

I am asking for anything programatically just within their own UI

Answer (score 2):

Not currently but you could put it on an Azure Storage Queue and process it to Table Storage and send an Email with Azure Functions.

Check out this page what is possible - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings

Comment: Wow that seems like an awful lot of work? I dont have control over the Table Storage bit. This is the leads collection process for Microsoft Office Apps. If I link to a Azure Storage Table, its mean to put lead info in there. However, I had no idea how to access the thing. Hence the email notification.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the easiest way to see the data is to use their desktop app

Use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Azure Storage Explorer doesn't send any notification emails.

Answer (score 0):

The lastest Azure product updates covering event-driven applications suggest to adopt these application patterns to react to events published by Azure Storage. These docs/resources might help to explore the application pattern and current platform/framework support.

Azure Storage

- [Reacting to Blob storage events (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)
- Did not found anything similar for Azure Tables - what about suggesting this on UserVoice?

CosmosDB

- [Working with the change feed support in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed)